# Django - Filter not returning objects in database

Tags: python, mysql, django

Attempting to filter a MYSQL database to return a set of objects created on a given day:

```
len(Model.objects.filter(x__year=year, x__month=month, x__day=day)
```

Checked the database and there are objects there. The previous line of code still returns no objects ~0.

What is causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe just that you have a single underscore in `x_month` -- should be `x__month`.

Comment: Try also len(list(Model.objects.filter(...)), i.e. use `list` to force the filter to execute.